# how to determine when to use differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am confused on the theory behind differential or partial differential equations. I know for calculus you take the integral and that gives the area under a curve. what determines the use of differential or partial differential equations.

Comment: Differential equations typically arise in situations where how fast a quantity is changing depends on how large it is at a particular point in time. For example, if you're studying how a cup of coffee cools down to room temperature, then the closer the coffee is to room temperature at a given moment, the slower its temperature will be dropping at that time. This gives a relation between the temperature function and its own derivative with respect to time.

Comment: It seems you're looking for applications rather than theory. *Area under a curve*, for example, doesn't really define an integral or explain the theory behind it. Rather, it's just one of the many uses/applications of integration. The subject of differential equations is like a broader category or extension of basic calculus. Many physical laws are written in the language of DEs. [edited for friendlier language]